# tkinter menu accelerator duplicating callbacks

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, callback, menu

I'm seeing some strange behavior running Python 3.7.6 and tkinter 8.6 on MacOS 10.14.6.

I've bound "Delete" to a function, and also added a menu command that triggers the same function. I've also added an accelerator option to the menu command, which only displays the text and doesn't actually create the shortcut (as noted [here](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/menus.html)).

Except, in this case, it *does* seem to create a shortcut: pressing the "Delete" key triggers my function twice: once for the bound command, and a second time from the accelerator. Removing either the binding or the accelerator cause it to only trigger once; of course, removing both causes the keybind to no longer activate. It works fine when triggered from the menu, and this doesn't seem to happen with other keys or key combos.

I'm not sure whether I've missed a detail about Tkinter programming or I'm encountering a technical issue.  I made sure to try a different keyboard, and am unsure whether it might be a bug with Tkinter on Mac.

The following code consistently exhibits my issue:

```
from tkinter import *

def bar(event=None):
    print("Called bar")

def foo(event=None):
    print("Called foo")

root = Tk()
menubar = Menu(root)
filemenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)


#works fine
filemenu.add_command(label="Something else", command=bar, accelerator="Control-s")
root.bind("<Control-s>", bar)

#triggers twice when using the "Del" key
filemenu.add_command(label="Delete a thing", command=foo, accelerator="Delete")
root.bind("<Delete>", foo)


menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=filemenu)
root.config(menu=menubar)
root.mainloop()
```

Triggering each shortcut once generates the following output:

```
Called bar
Called foo
Called foo
```

So this leaves me with two questions:

1. Can this be replicated by other people?
2. How might I resolve or work around it?

Comment: I'm able to replicate it on my OSX system. I can't explain it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also had this issue, and looking at the code it appears that it definitely *does* add bindings for your accelerators. In my app I worked around it by not binding the key presses on OSX but it's hardly ideal..
There is a Tk bug for this: https://core.tcl-lang.org/tk/tktedit?name=ead70921a9665f57d2fbcfb3cdee51391858bc96

Comment: Per the linked discussion, this bug was fixed in Tk version 8.6.10.  I can't confirm that, though, as I've long since moved past this project.

Answer (score 0):

Your code worked fine on my `windows` system running `Python 3.7`, but believing there are some issues with tkinter on MacOS, you can try the using the themed tk `ttk Menubutton` widget and see if it works any better. The look of the ttk Menu might slightly differ from the tk Menu design.

Here is your posted code with the `ttk Menubutton`:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

def bar(event=None):
    print("Called bar")

def foo(event=None):
    print("Called foo")

root = tk.Tk()

# create a ttk menubutton
mb = ttk.Menubutton(root, text="File")

# create a cascade of menu options for this menubutton mb
mb.menu = tk.Menu(mb, tearoff=0)

mb.menu.add_command(label="Something else", command=bar, accelerator="Control-s")
root.bind("<Control-s>", bar)

mb.menu.add_command(label="Delete a thing",command=foo, accelerator="Delete")
root.bind("<Delete>", foo)

mb.configure(menu=mb.menu)
mb.pack(side='left')

root.mainloop()
```

I hope it works!

Comment: Your code does indeed work: another point for ttk, I suppose.  Unfortunately, the MenuButton you employ is a little different than the Menu widget, which I'm using for the window's menubar.  I'll probably end up binding a different key.